# Matplotlib: How to get Binomial Likelihood Function

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability

I'm trying to replicate a plot that I've found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405005/what-is-the-likelihood-function-of-having-heads-8-times-out-of-10-toss):
[image]

However, I'm struggling with the y-scale of the Likelihood function, i.e. `binom(n=10, k=4)`. I'm using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import binom
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
ax.plot(x, binom.pmf(n=10, k=4, p=x))
```

However, this gives me the following plot:
[image]

We clearly see that the x-axis matches between both plots - however, in the first plot, the blue line suggest a value around 2.5 for `x=0.4`. Is ist just scaled by a factor to increase readability?

Comment: IMO, the graphics you try to replicate is to blame. For discrete probability distributions such as the binomial distribution the probabilities for each possible event must be <= 1. Only the probability densities of continuous distributions can be greater than 1. It's probably better to plot the binomial not as a continuous line, but rather as a series of dots.